# Sequelize - left join MAX date from same table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, min

Current dataset:

```
id   userId   enrolledAt   active
1    22       2020-01-01   false 
2    22       2020-05-05   true
```

How to retrieve all active records where enrolledAt should equal to the MIN(enrolledAt) from all active and inactive records for given user.

Starting point:

```
const include = [{
  model: User,
  as: 'user'
}];

Enrollment.findAll({ include, where: { active: true } });
```

Comment: You have mentioned `MAX date` in the title `MIN(enrolledAt)` in the body. I think it is confusing. I request you to share the SQL query that you want to generate.

Comment: Will group by user id having enrolled date as a minimum date serve your purpose?